Linking data based off a value within a group
Good afternoon, I have two tables (call them table a and b), the first has one row  per id, with  a number attributed too it as follows:
|  ID  | Number | 
|  1   |   10   |
|  2   |   21   |
|  3   |   09   |
|  4   |   19   |

The 2nd table is larger and has the same ID's, but multiple rows per ID. What I want is to be able to bring out every row of data that has a number either greater than or equal to the number in the table above:
e.g. ID 1 would bring back say number 10-15 if it had 15 rows of data
ID 2 would bring back 21-29 etc
I can do it for an individual ID but how do I do it for multiple ID's?

What does your second table look like? What RDBMS are you using?  What have you tried so far?

So it looks the same but with more rows of data per ID and more column items. I'm not interested in the rows of data before the example number in the table above, just the rows after and including. I'm on SSMS. As stated I managed joining a and b where the b.number is >=  a.number on a singular ID but not sure how to get it for more than one ID

If I understood correctly , maybe the following would help you.
SELECT a.id,a.number,b.id,b.number
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id AND b.number >= a.number;


If you want to limit the search to specific id-s add a WHERE clause.
